# The wi-fi card doesn't connect

Tags: wireless, 16.04, connection, atheros, adapter

Since I have installed Ubuntu 16.04, my wireless network adapter doesn't want to connect to the internet. Can anybody help me fix this?

Model:
Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my problem here [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203079&highlight=Qualcomm+Atheros+AR928X+Wireless+Network+Adapter](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203079&highlight=Qualcomm%20Atheros%20AR928X%20Wireless%20Network%20Adapter)

I have applied the solution proposed by the user varunendra presented in the page 1 : 
Code:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```